# Remove tr from table via tr id

Tags: jquery

Im trying to remove a tr from a table with jquery

I call it like this where `file` is a variable containing the id of the `tr`

```
$('table .report_table_list tr #'+file).remove();
```

any reason why it does not work?

table sample

```
<table id="desktop_tablel" class="patientselect_desktop report_table_list">
    <thead style="overflow-y: scroll; display: table; table-layout: fixed; width: calc(100% - 1px);">
        <tr class="header">
            <th style="width: 300px;" class="header_cell nobreak">Report name</th>
            <th style="width: 125px;" class="header_cell nobreak">Date created</th>
            <th style="width: 30px;" class="header_cell nobreak"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody id="reportsummary" class="desktop" style="overflow: auto; height: 200px; display: block;">
       <tr id="Ward_Round_Summary-17-01-2018_15-05.html" data-report="Ward_Round_Summary-17-01-2018_15-05.html" class="select data-row  odd">
            <td style="width: 300px;" data-report="Ward_Round_Summary-17-01-2018_15-05.html" class="listing_cell open_report">
                <div class="plCell_desktop">
                    <label>Ward_Round_Summary</label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 125px;" data-report="Ward_Round_Summary-17-01-2018_15-05.html" class="listing_cell open_report">
                <div class="plCell_desktop">
                    <label>17-01-2018 15:05</label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 30px;" class="listing_cell">
                <div class="">
                    <input data-report="Ward_Round_Summary-17-01-2018_15-05.html" type="button" class="removeButton buttons delete_report" value="x">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JQUERY**

```
function reportDelete(file) {
    var folder = "/reports/process/";
    $.ajax({
        url: '../deleteReport.php',
        data: {'folder':folder,'file' : file },
        success: function (response) {
            console.log("success",file); // file contains -> Ward_Round_Summary-17-01-2018_15-05.html
            $('#'+file).remove(); // does not work
            $('table .report_table_list tr #'+file).remove(); // does not work
        },
        error: function () {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Remove the space. The selector should be `'.... tr#' + file`. Voting to close as a typo

Comment: You could also use `$('#'+file).remove();` as element IDs should be unique.

Comment: If you're removing something via its ID, then just select the ID. They have to be unique, so there's no need to have to use the DOM tree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space character has a specific meaning in selectors.  For example, this selector:

```
'table .report_table_list'
```

would be looking for *any element* with the class `report_table_list` *within* a `<table>` element.  But that's not what your HTML has.  In your HTML the `<table>` element *itself* has that class.  Which would be this:

```
'table.report_table_list'
```

The same is true of the ID selector as well.  Once both are corrected, you get this:

```
'table.report_table_list tr#'+file
```

Though, since `id` is (or should be at least) unique, you can simplify the whole thing to:

```
'#'+file
```

**Edit:**  Upon additional debugging, it looks like the selector is also confused by the `.` character in your `file` value:

```
'#Ward_Round_Summary-17-01-2018_15-05.html'
```

The selector thinks it's a class specifier appended to the end.  Since `.` *is* allowed in an `id`, we just need to escape the character.  You may need to tweak where `file` comes from or do some string manipulation to escape the character, but this selector works:

```
'#Ward_Round_Summary-17-01-2018_15-05\\.html'
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/qxmbccjy/2/)

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but it did not remove it for some reason. Look ant my `JQuery` edit. and yes the `id`s are unique.

Comment: @morne: When your selectors run, do they find any matching elements?  If you run `$('#'+file)` in the browser console, what does it return?  What's in `file`?  Where does that value come from?

Comment: running that gives me a result. `e.fn.init[ prevObject...` and file is the id of the `tr`. in this case `Ward_Round_Summary-17-01-2018_15-05.html`

Comment: @morne: What is `$('#'+file).length`?  Basically, you need to determine if the jQuery selector is even finding what you expect it to.  And where in your code did you actually call the function?  Have you debugged to confirm the value of `file` or are you assuming?

Comment: okay, Length is 0.  but I dont understand, the id does exist. what could it be then?

Comment: @morne: Strange indeed.  It looks like it has to do with the `.` character in the `id`.  Which I *thought* was permitted?  Take a look at this sample: https://jsfiddle.net/qxmbccjy/  Then this one: https://jsfiddle.net/qxmbccjy/1/  The only difference is removing the `.` from the `id` and the selector.  Looks like the `id` can't have that character.

Comment: @morne: It just hit me.... An `id` *can* have a `.`, but a jQuery *selector* gets confused by it because it also looks like a class specifier.

Comment: Is there no escape char for it? face palm

Comment: bingo ->  `file = file.replace(".html", "\\.html");`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('table.report_table_list tr#'+file).remove();
```

Please update your code like above.

We don't need space when the class or id selector present in the same element.

Also you can simply use like this, if your id is unique.

```
 $('#'+file).remove();
```